# Getting AttributeError in a beginner's Python game creating project while using pygame

Tags: python, attributeerror

I am stuck on a game writing exercise from a beginner Python book called Python Crash Course. At this point, it's very basic. It's only supposed to create a window where an image of the ship would load in the bottom center. I'm certain that I copied the code almost line for line, and encountered examples online that pretty much do what I did here, but I still keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/.../chapteraliens/alien_invasion.py", line 40, in <module>
    ai = AlienInvasion()
  File "c:/Users/.../chapteraliens/alien_invasion.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.ship = Ship(self)
  File "c:\Users\...\chapteraliens\ship.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
AttributeError: 'AlienInvasion' object has no attribute 'get_rect'
```

And here are the 3 files that I have created. I don't think it has anything to do with settings.py, but I included it just in case because it's very short.

**alien_invasion.py**

```
import sys
import pygame

from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship

class AlienInvasion:
    """Overall class to manage game assets and behavior."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game and create the game resources."""
        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion") 

        self.settings = Settings()
        self.ship = Ship(self)

        self.bg_color = (self.settings.bg_color)
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
            (self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))

    def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop for the game."""
        while True:
            """Watch for the keyboard and mouse events."""
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()

            # Set the visual elements of the game.
            self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)
            self.ship.blitme()

            # Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
            pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    # Make a game instance, and run the game.
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

**ship.py**

```
import pygame

class Ship:
    """The class that handles the management of the ship."""

    def __init__(self, screen):
        """Initialize the ship and set up the starting position."""
        self.screen = screen
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

        # Load the ship image and get its rect.
        self.image = pygame.image.load("ship_w.bmp")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Start each new ship at the bottom of center of the screen.
        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom

    def blitme(self):
        """Draw the ship at its current location."""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

**settings.py**

```
class Settings:
    """A class to store settings for the game."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game's settings."""
        # Screen settings
        self.screen_width = 800
        self.screen_height = 600
        self.bg_color = (40, 40, 40)
```

I then tried to comment out the lines to do with the get_rect error, but that only made it so that the same error appeared with the "blit" line this time. The lines that I commented out and the new error is as follows:

```
...
        # self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
...
        # self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom
...
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/.../chapteraliens/alien_invasion.py", line 41, in <module>
    ai.run_game()
  File "c:/Users/.../chapteraliens/alien_invasion.py", line 33, in run_game
    self.ship.blitme()
  File "c:\Users\...\chapteraliens\ship.py", line 20, in blitme
    self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
AttributeError: 'AlienInvasion' object has no attribute 'blit'
```

Might it be that I'm using the get_rect() and blit() functions incorrectly somehow? And that's if the whole thing is not a simple small error that wasn't able to catch.

Comment: Your `Ship` class takes a screen object as its init argument but you pass an `AlienInvasion` instance here: `self.ship = Ship(self)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Ship()` expects `screen` as argument but in `AlienInvasion.__init__` you use `self` in `Ship(self)` so you use instace of  `AlienInvasion`, not `screen` - so later it tries to get `AlienInvasion.get_rect()` and you get your error.

You have to first create `self.screen` and then use it with `Ship()`

```
self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))

self.ship = Ship(self.screen)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I confirmed that the code works after the edits. Then another question appeared on my mind while I was trying to experiment with the code:  If I change ship.py's init arguments from `(self, screen)` to `(self, game)`; then change

`self.screen = screen` to `self.screen = game.screen`
`self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()` to `self.screen_rect = game.screen.get_rect()`

it actually works when I use it as `self.ship = Ship(self)`. I can't say that I get how or why this works exactly. It still uses the `AlienInvasion` instance, so shouldn't the problem still persist?

Comment: but now when you run code you have something like `self.screen = AlienInvasion.screen` and `self.screen_rect = AlienInvasion.screen.get_rect()` - and it is correct. In previos version you had `self.screen = AlienInvasion`  `self.screen_rect = `AlienInvasion.get_rect()`. The difference is `.screen` in `AlienInvasion.screen` and it makes that it works. In original code you used only `AlienInvasion`, in my aswer i send `AlienInvasion.screen` to `Ship`, and in the new code you use `AlienInvasion.screen` inside `Ship`